# Unable to total number of words that appear in a table

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble trying to find the total amount of times a word appears in an entire table.
My code currently just counts the number of times the word appears in each row. How do I get around this issue?

```
SELECT comments, COUNT(*) AS total FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%&#39;%' 
GROUP BY comments
```

If you would like anymore code please ask :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get `COUNT`

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%abcd%'
```

you can get all comments that match the word using only `WHERE`

```
SELECT  comments AS total FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%abcd%'
```

if you want `COUNT` to repeat along with comment then `CROSS APPLY can be used

```
select * from (SELECT  comments  
FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%abcd%' ) T
CROSS APPLY 
  ( SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%abcd%' ) T2
```

Comment: If I remove the group by I get this error.... Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'AE.Comments' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Dan_JAVA_SQL, only MYSQL allows it with out group, i updated it for other sql.

Answer (score 0):

Will just the number be enough?

```
SELECT COUNT(comments) AS total FROM AE
WHERE comments like '%&#39;%'
```